# Pointing to Abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I've a basic knowledge of abstract class. Its that it cannot be instantiated itself but with class who is implemented it or the anonymous classes. I hope its right..!

But I've came across a below code.

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
```

And here's a `newInstance` sourc code:

```
public static SAXParserFactory newInstance()
  86:     throws FactoryConfigurationError
  87:   {
  88:     ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  89:     if (loader == null)
  90:       {
  91:         loader = SAXParserFactory.class.getClassLoader();
  92:       }
  93:     String className = null;
  94:     int count = 0;
  95:     do
  96:       {
  97:         className = getFactoryClassName(loader, count++);
  98:         if (className != null)
  99:           {
 100:             try
 101:               {
 102:                 Class t = (loader != null) ? loader.loadClass(className) :
 103:                   Class.forName(className);
 104:                 return (SAXParserFactory) t.newInstance();
 105:               }
 106:             catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
 107:               {
 108:                 className = null;
 109:               }
 110:             catch (Exception e)
 111:               {
 112:                 throw new FactoryConfigurationError(e,
 113:                      "error instantiating class " + className);
 114:               }
 115:           }
 116:       }
 117:     while (className == null && count < 3);
 118:     return new gnu.xml.stream.SAXParserFactory();
 119:   }
 120: 
 121:   private static String getFactoryClassName(ClassLoader loader, int attempt)
 122:   {
 123:     final String propertyName = "javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory";
 124:     switch (attempt)
 125:       {
 126:         case 0:
 127:           return System.getProperty(propertyName);
 128:         case 1:
 129:           try
 130:             {
 131:               File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"));
 132:               file = new File(file, "lib");
 133:               file = new File(file, "jaxp.properties");
 134:               InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
 135:               Properties props = new Properties();
 136:               props.load(in);
 137:               in.close();
 138:               return props.getProperty(propertyName);
 139:             }
 140:           catch (IOException e)
 141:             {
 142:               return null;
 143:             }
 144:         case 2:
 145:           try
 146:             {
 147:               String serviceKey = "/META-INF/services/" + propertyName;
 148:               InputStream in = (loader != null) ?
 149:                  loader.getResourceAsStream(serviceKey) :
 150:                 SAXParserFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(serviceKey);
 151:               if (in != null)
 152:                 {
 153:                   BufferedReader r =
 154:                      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
 155:                   String ret = r.readLine();
 156:                   r.close();
 157:                   return ret;
 158:                 }
 159:             }
 160:           catch (IOException e)
 161:             {
 162:             }
 163:           return null;
 164:         default:
 165:           return null;
 166:       }
 167:   }
 168:
```

If you see the code, there is a possibility of returning Reference type of `SAXParserFactory` is at line number 104 and 118.

At line 104, Its creating dynamic class. I want to know how newly created class can be casted into abstract class type `SAXParserFactory` ? I'm confused Here..!

And after Instantiating `SAXParserFactory`, below code runs

```
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
```

So once `SAXParserFactory` is Instantiated, newSAXParser() method of abstract class `SAXParserFactory` class should be implemented before using it, But From where its being called ? Because the class who implements `SAXParserFactory` class is a class which is created at run time!

Comment: This is a complex mixture of reflection and class loading, do you have experience with either of them?

Comment: any instance can be cast to one of its superclasses or to any of the interfaces it implements (e.g. you can cast any instance of `Integer` to `Number` or `Object`) The class represented by `t` must be a subclass of `SAXParserFactory`

Comment: *Line 104:* `t` is the Class object for a class that implements (subclasses) `SAXParserFactory`, so the actual class is not abstract and it can be cast without issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
97: className = getFactoryClassName(loader, count++);
```

This line returns the full name of a class which *extends* `SAXParserFactory`.
An example might be

```
oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory
```

Then

```
102: Class t = (loader != null) ? loader.loadClass(className)
103:                            : Class.forName(className);
```

Asks the *Classloader* for the `JXSAXParserFactory` `Class` object (`Class<JXSAXParserFactory>`).

```
104: return (SAXParserFactory) t.newInstance();
```

`Class#newInstance` is invoked, which in this case means the no-args constructor of `JXSAXParserFactory` is called.

Being the `JXSAXParserFactory extends SAXParserFactory`, it can be **upcasted**.
This is the right term.

*Extending* means inheriting the father **signature**. Obviously by upcasting, you loose the additional exposed members of the sub-class.

---

`SAXParserFactory#newSAXParser` will always be limited at returning a `SAXParser`, but the underlying implementation (basically, the logic) will be different.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: is that really up-casting: from `Object` to `SAXParseFactory`? I believe that is a down-cast, (up-casting is always allowed; down-casting involves type checking, which definitively is the case here - you'll get an cast exception if `t` is not a class extending `SAXParseFactory`) {the JLS uses these terms at all, it uses Narrowing/Widening Reference Conversion}

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger being this is old code, yes, it's down-casting. Newer version of this, I suppose, would use a generic Class<T>. However my statement was referring in general (JXSAXParserFactory extends SAXParserFactory), not really to that line of code

Comment: @LppEdd "This line returns the full name of a class which extends SAXParserFactory", How do we know SAXParserFactory is implemented by the class Class's object ?

Comment: @Trisha mmh I'm not following you. What do you mean? Try with some other words.

Comment: @LppEdd, In above code `className` returns the name (`oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory`) of new Class's instance. And that class is going to be the class which will be implementing `SAXParserFactory` abstact class. But where this implementation is being done ? Which part of code it says that now `SAXParserFactory` is implemented by `oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory` ?

Comment: @Trisha nowhere here. That JXSAXParserFactory resides in a different JAR package, and is found because it is inside the application classpath. Other than that you know it via its JavaDoc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b12024/oracle/xml/jaxp/JXSAXParserFactory.html

Comment: @Trisha That class is already implemented. Its bytecode definition is already inside the application.

Comment: @LppEdd, Okay..! Makes sense....but then what about 'SAXParser', Its also a abstract class. And `SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); ` is actually a `oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory` class. Then How and who is implementing 'SAXParser' class now ?

Comment: @Trisha SAXParser acts just as a "signature" in this case, the real implementation is provided by someone else. It's the same concept as with JXSAXParserFactory

Comment: @Trisha https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28391/oracle/xml/jaxp/JXSAXParser.html